# Login/signup script in python using sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have created a login/signup script in python using sqlite3 and kivy. Affter creating the database, the user can enter their username, email and password. The password is hashed before being inserted into the database. The signup function works, however I am having an error with validating the user's username and password with those in the database, where the code outputs 'login sucessful' after a wrong username/password.

```
    def login_menu_press(self):
        login = False

        lusername = self.login_username.text
        lpassword = self.login_password.text
        print(f"Your username is {lusername}, and your password is {lpassword}.")
        self.login_username.text = ""
        self.login_password.text = ""

        # Hashing inputted password
        context = CryptContext(
            schemes=["pbkdf2_sha256"],
            default="pbkdf2_sha256",
            # More rounds = more secure, but slower to hash
            pbkdf2_sha256__default_rounds=50000
        )

        # Hash the inputted password
        hash_pass = context.hash(lpassword)


        # Connect to database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')

        # Create cursor
        c = conn.cursor()

        # Query database
        command = f"SELECT * from users WHERE username='{lusername}' AND Password = '{hash_pass}';"
        c.execute(command)
        if not c.fetchone():
            print("Login successful")
            login = True
        else:
            print("Login failed")
```

I belive that the error persits after the Query database comment, any help is appreciated, thanks!

I excpeted that login sucessful outputs when the username and password is supposed to be correct, which is correct. However, the code outputs this again when the username and password is anything else random.

***Edit*** the password inputted by the user is hashed with the same algorithm that was used to hash the password that the user signs up with, therefore the hashed values will be the same.

Comment: the password that you compare will be different, why not display calculated password with the password received, there you will see that you probably did not enter the password with the same hash

Comment: Habibi, the password stored in DATABASE should be decrypted when you want to compare it to that used in the login.

Comment: You have the condition `if not c.fetchone()` the wrong way around. Your code tells you that the login is successful if the cursor returned no data (i.e. username/password didn't match, hence login actually not successful) and that your login failed if the cursor did return some data (i.e. username/password matched, so valid credentials were given). So if you are always getting 'Login successful', then in truth you are actually always getting failed logins. You will have to investigate why the hash you get when you log in doesn't match the hash stored in the database.

Comment: I should also point out to you that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. If you enter a username something like `X' OR 1 = 1 --` then your code will likely return successful logins all the time. Use bind parameters: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders .

Answer (score 0):

Hash alghoritm which you used use salt, thus for exatly same input string it will output different hash values:

```
    # Hash the inputted password
    lpassword = "Rambo"
    hash_pass = context.hash(lpassword)
    print(hash_pass)
    hash_pass = context.hash(lpassword)
    print(hash_pass)
    hash_pass = context.hash(lpassword)
    print(hash_pass)

$pbkdf2-sha256$50000$wniP0br3XguBsJbSuvc.xw$vmebKLd0Uvz4IF7DbX/TzCgD5p1/cmPYApaf2eKeZ4w
$pbkdf2-sha256$50000$wJjT2tv7H8NY633vXYvROg$D0CxPTfO8jIaLPHvUtawhzKMX75LqDYSNa.z3Bf/58s
$pbkdf2-sha256$50000$tZbSWmvNmdPau9eas1ZKaQ$qMVGQWPtlLvFZ/WlG.iDO7.jIHhFiirMZw0gysfqXhs
```

So there is no way to match previously inserted and hashed password value. You have to use hash function which will always generate same value for same input string, like SHA-256 for instance. Replace:

```
    hash_pass = context.hash(lpassword)
```

with:

```
    import hashlib  # on top of main.py
    hash_pass = hashlib.sha256(lpassword.encode()).hexdigest()
```

And comment out this part of code:

```
    context = CryptContext(
        schemes=["pbkdf2_sha256"],
        default="pbkdf2_sha256",
        # More rounds = more secure, but slower to hash
        pbkdf2_sha256__default_rounds=50000
    )
```

Also you you have to change your condition: `if not c.fetchone():` to `if c.fetchone():`

Comment: Hi, this gives an error message ' passlib.exc.UnknownHashError: hash could not be identified'. Also, what does hexdigest() do??

Comment: So you also have a problem with passlib, not line proposed by me. Just comment out lines:

`context = CryptContext(
        schemes=["pbkdf2_sha256"],
        default="pbkdf2_sha256",
        # More rounds = more secure, but slower to hash
        pbkdf2_sha256__default_rounds=50000
    )`

Comment: As long sha256 returns binary value which cannot be directly casted to String, hexdigest() converts every byte of calculated hash to hex value representation. In short it returns String combined with hex for every byte of generated hash, for example `9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08`. First byte of hash is 0x9f second is 0x86, third 0xd0 and so on.